# AWS QnA Bot Solution Handlebars not getting correct interaction count

Tags: amazon-web-services, handlebars.js, aws-cloudformation, amazon-lex

I followed the [AWS tutorial to get started with using HandleBars with an AWS QnA Bot](https://github.com/aws-solutions/aws-qnabot/blob/main/docs/Handlebars_README.md). As far as I'm aware, I've followed the directions. However, the output makes me think I'm missing a step somewhere.

[My output is not displaying the interaction count correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOo4C.png)
It seems to be keeping track of 2 separate values. The first time I ask it for my interaction count, it'll give me a value currently in the low 30's. The second time it will jump to a value in the 60's and count upwards from there.

As far as I'm aware, [my question and HandleBars expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t14Dg.png) is the same as the tutorial. I even copy pasted the values in just to be sure. I've also made sure to do a Lex Rebuild but this did not change anything.

Can someone please explain why it isn't working as expected?

Comment: Can you maybe expand on this a bit more? What behaviour do you see when you interact with the bot in an incognito browsing mode?

Comment: The behavior seems to be the [same in incognito as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNl8C.png). The bot definitely has memory storage somewhere because it is keeping track of the total count but I'm not sure why there are 2 different numbers.

Comment: It sounds like there might be a global variable at play here that's storing the overall invocation count rather than session-based invocation count. Could you possibly share the Lambda code?
Post on global variables that might help with debugging: https://www.completecloudarchitects.com/blog/aws-lambda-global-variables/

Comment: It appears that this example makes use of DynamoDB to store the user information. If you're testing with the same User ID (as defined here: https://github.com/aws-solutions/aws-qnabot/blob/72e684800124acfa49fbd8b80a2e7079fb44ee92/docs/Handlebars_README.md) then it would make sense that Lex retrieves the existing user record and increments the value by 1. 
Please check your input values when starting the Lex interaction and perhaps review that against the DynamoDB tables and you should find your answer.